# inequality in Sobolev spaces

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $I\subset \Bbb R$ be a bounded interval and $u∈ W^{1,p} (I)$.
Let $(u_n)_n\subset C^{\infty}(I)$ such that $u_n\to u\in W^{1,p} (I)$.

I see in some proof that $||u_n'-u'||_{L^p} \le ||u_n-u||_{W^{1,p} (I)}$.

Where this inequality come from?

Many thanks for any help in the right direction.

Comment: Because $\|f\|_{W^{1, p}}$ has a term involving the $L^p$ norm of $f'$.

Comment: Right! many thanks! it is because  $||u||_{ W^{1,p} (I)} = (||u||_{L^p} + ||u'||_{L^p} )^{1/p}$